# $f$ is continuous & real valued on $E$ then {$p \in E : f(p) \leq 0$},{$p \in E : f(p) = 0$},{$p \in E : f(p) \geq 0$} closed

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $E, E'$ be metric spaces, $f: E \rightarrow E'$ a continuous function. Show that if $S$ is a closed subset of $E'$ then $f^{-1}(S)$ is a closed function. Derive from this result that if $f$ is continuous and real-valued on $E$ then the sets {$p \in E : f(p) \leq 0$}, {$p \in E : f(p) = 0$}, {$p \in E : f(p) \geq 0$} are closed.

I have proven the first result. I know that all $f(p)$ fall into at least one of the above sets, and points $p$ where $f(p) = 0$ are in all three sets. What should I construct as my closed set in $E$ or $E'$ so that the above sets are closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\{p:f(p) \leq 0\}=f^{-1}((-\infty,0])$$ $$\{p:f(p) = 0\}=f^{-1}(\{0\})$$ $$\{p:f(p) \geq 0\}=f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$$

Since $f$ is continuous and $[0,+\infty),(-\infty,0],\{0\}$ are closed subests of $\Bbb{R}$ we have that their inverse images are closed subsets of $E$.